# Sending commands to azure from C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, azure

Is there any library that would allow me to send commands to Azure from C#, instead of sending it from Power Shell? For instance, command like `Set-MsolDomainAuthentication -DomainName $domainname -FederationBrandName $domainname -Authentication Federated -IssuerUri $issueruri -LogOffUri $logoffuri`.

The idea is that we want ASP.Net webservice that would receive a command in API call, and then execute it on Azure instead of running command in power shell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, azure provide multiple library which could send commands(send request to the azure management side) to Azure from C#.

If you want to manage azure AD, I suggest you could try to use azure ad graph api.

> The Azure Active Directory Graph API provides programmatic access to Azure AD through REST API endpoints. Applications can use the Graph API to perform create, read, update, and delete (CRUD) operations on directory data and objects.

More details about what is graph api, you could refer to this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-graph-api).

More details about the graph api operation, you could refer to this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-graph-api).

Also, azure provide the client library to use graph api, you could install it from the [Nuget](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.ActiveDirectory.GraphClient/).

Notice: Not all the powershell command is supported in the AD graph api.

If you want to manage azure resources, I suggest you could use [azure Management Libraries](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn722415.aspx) or [azure management fluent library](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/tree/Fluent).

Both of these two library could manage your azure resources.

Answer (score 1):

I believe most of what you can do with powershell you can do with the Management Libraries (but I never used them so can't say for sure) https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn722415.aspx